# InstallShield 2010 InstallScript MSI Project - Manage Dialogs

Tags: installshield-2010

Anyone knows why is so difficult to remove a dialog from an InstallScript MSI project in InstallShield 2010? And how can i do this, e.g. remove the dialog asking for the Destination Path to install.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the dialog from the sequence in the Installation Designer (User Interface/Dialogs).